# How can I add extra multimedia types to Tridion?

Tags: tridion

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

I need small clarification regarding multimedia schema and types that it will allow.

By default, Tridion will allow some multimedia types like word document, JPEG, etc.

If I want to add some more types to it, is it possible in Tridion?

Suppose my application wants to make use of a multimedia type, which is not supported by Tridion. How can I make Tridion support that multimedia type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is described in the documentation, http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_F8456F78DAC540F2A72BC8EC70E2CA4C.